# Why use Business Objects as opposed to SQL/Crystal Reports or Jasper Reports?

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, business-objects

Looking at the cost of a license for SAP BusinessObjects, I am wondering what justifies using it. For appearances sake, it's a combination of MS Access and Crystal Reports with a SQL Server back-end. If I have already deployed such a setup, are there any advantages to reap by migrating?

I ask this because the information available on the web is rather sparse. Even Business Objects' own website does not provide me with any clear information as to **why** I should switch.

Does anyone have any experience in this avenue that they would be willing to share?

Comment: "Business Objects" is not really a piece of software, but a branding of BI tools owned by SAP. This question would entirely depend on what you're trying to accomplish with these tools and your budget and what piece of software you're specifically interested in.

Comment: Within the context of managing a database, and producing canned reports that can be run by management.

Comment: There are 10 or so different BI products under this branding and they all try to fill a different need for different sizes of organizations; whether any of them are worth the money for you is highly dependent on your specific situation.

Comment: I just identified my use case. Perhaps Business Objects is overkill for what I am attempting to accomplish. That was my original inclination, but I figured that the kind folks on SO would be able to provide better insight.

Answer (score 4):

One of the original selling points of BusinessObjects, which still holds true today but is no longer the only way to build reports, is its universe: a semantic layer that sits between your database and the end-user reports, and which translates the database model to easily understandable concepts or *objects* that are recognisable to the business (hence Business Objects).

The obvious advantages are:

- your users do not require knowledge of your data model or the SQL language to retrieve the information they need.
- the universe serves as an abstraction layer, which means that changes to your data model remain transparent to the end-user; their existing reports will continue to work.
- business definitions can be defined within the universe, and later changes can be implemented centrally without having to change each individual report.

In the recent years, Business Objects has transformed from 2 reporting tools (Desktop Intelligence and Web Intelligence) to a suite consisting of plethora of products which each serve a different need. So whether Business Objects is right for you will depend highly on your requirements as well as on your budget.